# Is there a way or tool to transform IntelliJ IDEA project to Makefile project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, makefile, build-tools

I have classic IntelliJ IDEA project (no maven or gradle). I want to transform this project to Makefile project.

For example, I have console application without some frameworks. This application consists of `Main.java, Class1.java and Class2.java`. The source files are in `src/com/site/` folder.

I want to write `make` in terminal and get `Main.jar`. Of course, I don't want to create Makefile manually.

Comment: If you're looking for a tool to do it for you, that's off topic for SO (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), item 4). If you're looking for a method (not a tool), that's _probably_ too broad, since it's pretty close to to "how do I extract information from an IDEA project" plus "how do I make a Makefile project [given that information]."

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to switch to Make (rather than Maven/Gradle)?  It's decidedly non-canonical for Java.

Comment: Oliver Charlesworth, I am a student. I can use java, but I have to give a Makefile project.

Comment: I doubt there is a tool that does this (there would be zero demand for such a thing).  Luckily in this case, the Makefile is trivial to construct manually.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth, of course, you are right. It is a simply task. But, if I have many java project, then it's boring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any solution. Therefore, I use this snippet:

```
someproject -p out
javac src/com/example/*.java -d out/
cd out/ && jar cfe someproject.jar com.example.Main  com/example/*.class && mv someproject.jar ../ && cd .. 
echo "#!/bin/bash" > someproject
echo 'java -jar $${BASH_SOURCE[0]}.jar' >> someproject
chmod a+x someproject
```